# Show that $\deg g(x)$ divides $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\Bbb F_p$. Recall that $[L : \Bbb F_p] = n$. Let $g(x) ∈ \Bbb F_p(x)$ be irreducible and divide $x^{p^n} - x$.
>   Show that $\deg g(x)$ divides $n$.

The hint is Consider the intermediate field extension where $g(x)$ has a root. However, I don't know how to use this hint and do this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=F_p(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $g.$ Then since $g|(x^{p^n}-x)$ it follows that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{p^n}-x,$ hence $\alpha\in L$ as $L$ is the splitting field. Then 
$$n=[L:F_p]=[L:E][E:F_p],$$
so $[E:F_p]|n.$ Note that since $g$ was irreducible $\deg(g)=[E:F_p],$ so $\deg(g)| n.$